# Can I obtain original data by multiplying varimax-rotated principal components with varimax-rotated unit length loadings?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, factor-rotation

I have perform conventional Empirical Orthogonal Function (EOF) analysis to my data set and obtain loadings (eigenvector scaled by square root of eigenvalue) and corresponding principal component.

Then I perform VARIMAX rotation to my loadings to obtain rotated loadings. I then normalize the resulting rotated loadings by dividing it with square root of sum of square of loading; therefore, finally I obtain rotated loadings with unit length.

My question is that

1. Can I calculate rotated principal components by multiplying original data with the unit length (normalized) rotated loadings?
2. Can I reconstruct original data by multiplying rotated principal components with corresponding rotated loadings

Thanks,